# Do non-observable atomics synchronize memory?

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic, compiler-optimization, c11

In general, C11 atomics not only guarantee the atomicity of the operation on the atomic object itself, but also provide memory synchronization for access to other (non-atomic) objects. However, I'm unclear whether this synchronization is a side-effect in itself that can be observed, in a strictly conforming program, independently of the atomic object, or if it is only meaningful when the atomic object performing the synchronization is accessed by all threads for which the synchronization needs to take place.

In particular, given a function such as:

```
void foo()
{
    _Atomic int x = 0;
    x++;
}
```

does the compiler need to generate any code for this function? Or, since the lifetime of `x` ends immediately with no opportunity for it to participate in synchronization with other threads, can the compiler optimize out the whole function?

Comment: I don't quite understand: You have a synchronization that is not observed and you asking if it's observable?

Comment: @dyp: For example, is there any way that calling `foo` could force previous stores to be visible to other threads, or some other similar observable effect? I think your confusion is the distinction between the observability of the atomic object itself (`x` in the code snippet) and the observability of potential side effects of modifying it.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense if the memory order for the atomic operation is sequentially consistent.

Comment: I'm not terribly sure about C, especially its atomic syntax, but it somehow feels to me like you're asking whether a program can observe whether UB is happening. If concucrrent operations aren't ordered, then you cannot say a lot about their relations.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm asking if there's any way to produce well-defined behavior using such a construct that depends on the compiler actually generating code for `foo`.

Comment: [Consider this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bca51522084f779): does the `seq_cst` operation imply an order of the relaxed atomic operations?

Comment: @R..: *As written* I don't think so, since nobody can observe the memory location for `x`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What about the ideas discussed on Casey's deleted answer, i.e. `foo(); relaxed_atomic_op(); foo();`? Since the atomics on `x` take place in the same thread, don't they impose on the total order, even though `x` is not observable, and thereby make the `relaxed_atomic_op()` effectively a full barrier (seq-cst)?

Comment: @R..: Which exact rule says that should happen? I think there's something similar in the C++ memory model, but I think it also requires some kind of dependency on a memory location... maybe spell out an example?

Comment: Short answer, the spec says no, as for what the compiler generates in real life, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we have 6.2.6.1 p9

> Loads and stores of objects with  atomic  types  are  done  with
>   `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics.

and the same holds for other operations on atomic objects.

So the stores in question have `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics. For these, it is then stated in 7.17.3 that they appear sequenced in a total order `S` of all such operations. All other modifications of objects that are in some ordering relation with events in `S` are constrained by that ordering.

The atomic objects themselves and the operations can be optimized out since the value is not observable. But the effect of `foo()` is that of a `memory_order_seq_cst` fence, and that fence should not be optimized out.

Comment: 7.17.3 is really dense reading. Could you cite what particular paragraphs establish that the `memory_order_seq_cst` is ordered with respect to anything else observable?

Comment: @R.. my reading is that the total order `S` must be consistent with the happens before order. Thus if you have an event in one thread that happens before a call to `foo()` at time `S1` and in another thread one that happens after such a call at time `S2`, and `S1 < S2`, these two events are ordered by happens before. This must be enforced by the as-if rule, even if the atomic update operation itself is optimized out. If the threads are in two separate comilation units, I see not much other possibility than using something that is equivalent to a fence to ensure that.

Comment: What is a "memory_order_seq_cst fence"?